# VLOOKUP within VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm trying to build a quick form to allow a user to calculate certain data using a data table. I am using `LOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` to achieve this.

This is my current formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(DP65,B6:CT36,(LOOKUP(DP67,(VLOOKUP(DP65,J52:K82,2)),C37:CT37)))
```

However, Excel is evaluating this to `#VALUE!`. Having step through the calculation, this is what it's trying to evaluate:

```
=VLOOKUP(DP65,$B$6:$CT$36,(LOOKUP(2500,"C26:CT26",C37:CT37)))
```

Obviously my issues lies here: `LOOKUP(2500,"C26:CT26",C37:CT37)` specifically where it's trying to parse `"C26:CT26"` as a valid table array.

Is there anyway that I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using the `INDIRECT` filter sorts this.

```
=VLOOKUP(DP65,B6:CT36,(LOOKUP(DP67,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(DP65,J52:K82,2)),C37:CT37)))
```